# Smooth bitmap rotation android SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I'd like to make my asteroids rotate constatly in my android game but I have completely no idea where to start.

I know I can rotate canvas, but I can't find a mathematical formula where to draw the object after the canvas is rotated by any angle, so that it is where it should be after I restore canvas.

I mean I figured it out only for 90, 180, 270 degrees, can you help me a bit? I just need a hint.

Thanks for you help!

EDIT: I finally figured it out just with canvas.rotate()

Comment: use a Matrix API for example Matrix.mapPoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `android.R.anim.linear_interpolator` from your animation XML file with `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"`

you can use it something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="3000"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:toDegrees="359" />
```

Using java :

```
//Rotate Asteroids
ImageView mAsteroids = (ImageView) findViewById(R.Id.Asteroids);
mAsteroids.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0F, 359.0F, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5F, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5F);  
rAnim.Interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
rAnim.RepeatCount = Animation.Infinite;
rAnim.Duration = 1500; //<-- you duration
mAsteroids.StartAnimation(rAnim);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering!

Its in xml though, where should I put it? To my layout? I don't use xml at all unfortunately :D

Comment: You're the man!! I'll try it out

Edit: ok so basically I dont know what "loading" is, and also eclipse doesnt find Dimension for some reason. 

Is there a way to give ImageView a bitmap? Because I scale my bitmaps depending on screen resolution and I'd like to rotate the scaled and loaded bitmap if that's possible

Comment: loadng was a typo, and you have to import Dimension class. to set image you can use something like `mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImage);`

Comment: What is I have my mAsteroids loaded as a bitmap? There is no ImageView used to draw it.

Comment: Dynamically you can create ImageView and give the layout parameters  as per your requirements

Comment: So what if I setContentView of my activity as instance of my SurfaceView class? I do not use layout at all by doing so. Also how would it work exactly, if I call canvas.drawBitmap(asteroid,x,y,null), would it draw it rotated? I mean if I used layout and just added my view instance to it.